# passing multiple values from select tag of html

Tags: django

how can I pass more than 1 value in this function
i tried but this does not work

```
<select onchange="myFunction(this)">
                <option value=''>new</option>
                {% for value in check %}
                <option value={{value.start}},{{value.end}}>{{ value.start }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
```

it is only passing {{value.start}}

Comment: Didn't you forgot to add quotes, so `value=".."` instead of `value=..`.

Comment: ohh it worked this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the comma is here seen as a separator, by quoting the part, you make sure that the entire value is seen as the attribute value, like:

```
<option value="{{value.start}},{{value.end}}">{{ value.start }}</option>
```